# How can I maintain the same column format in R data frame as in my SQL table?

Tags: sql, r, rodbc

I have a user id number in my data base that is made of 17 characters. When I fetch the table with RODBC I get the number in a scientific number format. How can I maintain the same format as in my SQL table?

I use MSSQL, R 3.0.2, RODBC as a connector.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your call to `sqlFetch` or `sqlQuery`, pass `as.is = TRUE` to retrieve everything as character vectors.  Then you can manually convert any other columns as you need.